# Intel RS2BL040 - RAID 10 Замена жесткого диска

Tags: debian, raid

Добрый день! 
Имею плату Intel RS2BL040 с 10 рейдом на борту. Debian 8.
Вынужден был произвести замену одного диска. После запуска сервера постоянно идет один сигнал каждые 3 секунды (это либо сбой или Rebuild).

Ниже даю список команд и результат:

```
megacli -PDList -aAll | egrep "Enclosure Device ID:|Slot Number:|Inquiry Data:|Error Count:|state"
```

**Результат:** 
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun down

```
megacli -PDRbld -ShowProg -PhysDrv [252:0] -aAll
```

**Результат:** Device(Encl-252 Slot-0) is not in rebuild process

```
megacli -AdpAutoRbld -Dsply -a0
```

**Результат:**Adapter 0: AutoRebuild is Enabled.

Не часто имею дело с рейдами, поэтому возникли вопросы:
1) Как разлечить бип сигнал от сбоя или от Rebuild?
2) Почему если AutoRebuild is Enabled то Device(Encl-252 Slot-0) is not in rebuild process?
3) Подходит ли megacli к RS2BL040?
4) Что я не так делаю?)

Comment: Сделал следующим образом: 1) Очистил новый диск командой megacli -PDClear -Start -PhysDrv [252:0] -a0 и запустил вручную Rebuild  следующей командой megacli -PDRbld -Start -PhysDrv [252:0] -a0 Ребилд запустился займет около 3,5 часа, надеюсь результат будет позитивным) Но я не могу понять почему не начался автоматический ребилд?

Comment: Ребилд закончился удачно. 2ТБ = 300 минут.

Comment: Кто даст ответ печему не срабатывает AutoRebuild и как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

`megacli` устарел. Попробуйте более удобный (как по командам, так и по формату выходных данных) инструмент - `storcli`. Версия 1.19.04 лежит [здесь](http://docs.avagotech.com/docs/1.19.04_StorCLI.zip).

Что бы началась пересборка массива - попробуйте перевести диск в состояние `HotSpare` такой командой:

```
storcli /c0/eX/sY add hotsparedrive
```

Что бы узнать номера X и Y - выполните команду

```
storcli /c0/eall/sall show
```

и посмотрите какой диск у вас в состоянии `UGood`.

Comment: не рискнул устанавливать storcli, но взял на заметку. Спасибо.